# how to make lines of mask/image thicker using material nodes in blender

Tags: materials, procedural

I got an image from google images, and i am using that image in a material, but i want the lines in the image thicker[image] So I was thinking, is there a way to make the line thicker, since making similar pattern procedurally or using photoshop maight take some time. Thank you

Comment: Try using math (power or greater than or other) maybe?

Comment: the math node(power or greater than will only make it darker, not thicker.

Comment: ohh so it only works on procedural lines? And I forgot it actually makes the line bigger. Oopsies

Comment: it works on all lines, but in this case, it will only make the line darker but not thicker, since there is no falloff in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it, that I think you can get away with based on the fact your image is black and white, and is relatively simple. The graph looks like this:

[image: Thicken1]

The idea is simple - make 5 separate "instances" of your image, offset 4 of them slightly (one in each direction), and add (or multiply in this case) them together. For the sample image that I chose, I offset by both .002 and -.002 for each of the X and Y axes, and multiplied them together (to copy the darks) with the original image. As you can see from the image below (which represents the original image), that the lines are much thinner.

[image: Thicken2]

As a side note, the "clamp" checkboxes are optional - I just often use them as a matter of habit to keep things in range and so I know there's no wacky HDR stuff going on behind the scenes.